# Is the mathematics in my answer valid? (C is the right answer)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

[image]

I have a good understanding of the concepts at hand, but I'm not so good at the mathematics part. I know the answer already (C), but would like to understand the mathematical way of determining it.

I tried:
$$8 = \frac{4m}{2d^2}$$

and $4 / 2 = 2$ and $2 \times 8 = 16$. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Let me gently suggest that if you are "not so good at the mathematics part", then you really *don't* have a good understanding of the concepts at hand, and you do yourself no favor by fooling yourself into believing otherwise.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: @WillO and if you told the O.P. this mockery, by what you helped? If you can help, OK, if not, then not, but why mock a person that asks for help?

Comment: @Sarabetorrius What is the formula that gives the acceleration produced by an object on a test object of unit mass? Tell us the formula.

Comment: @Sofia:  I'm sure it is possible, and perhaps even likely, that the OP will ignore my advice.  But it's good advice, if he takes it he will benefit, and if he does not, there's no harm done.  I think it's always a good thing to try to help people, even though we don't always succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a homework-problem website, let me answer anyway.

$$F=ma=\frac{GmM}{r^2} \implies a = G\frac{M}{r^2} $$

$$ G\frac{4M}{d^2} = 8 \text{ m s}^{-2} \implies G \frac{M}{d^2} = 2 \text{ m s}^{-2} \implies G \frac{M}{(d/2)^2} = G\frac{4M}{d^2} = 8 \text{ m s}^{-2}$$

I think the answer should be C if I didn't make any silly algebra mistake, which I think I haven't.

Comment: You don't need to promise just saying :)

Comment: this is correct, but a nicer solution IMHO is to notice that $M/r^2$ is the same for both planets.

Comment: Indeed it would be nicer but since the OP *wanted the mathematical way of determining it* I thought I would go as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something simple, but mass divided by radius squared is the same in both cases, so I would vote for (C).

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake. looks like I understood it wrong

Comment: can you show how to work this out?

Comment: @Sarabettorius: I gave a hint in my answer. I am not sure giving more than a hint for a homework question would be appropriate, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind That g ~ M and g ~ 1/R^2. So in your problem the mass of planet Y is 4 times smaller than the mass of planet X. Following this the g of Y should be 4 times smaller : 8/4 = 2. But it's radius is also 2 times smaller so because g~1/R^2, you should mulltiply it by 4 : 2*4=8. Finally The gravitational acc. of planet Y is 8m/s^2 (the same as planet X).
Correct answer is C.

Answer (score 0):

The value of g (in your case 8ms^-2) of a planet depends on his mass m, radius r (half diameter) and the gravitational constant G.

g=G*m/r^2

your 2 cases:

1) g_1=8 ms^-2 --> 8=G*4M/(2d/2)^2 --> GM/d^2=2 (take this for the second case too)

2) g_2=G*M/(d/2)^2 --> g_2=4GM/d^2 --> g_2= 4*(GM/d^2)=4*2=8 ms^-2

both are equal --> correct answer C

Comment: additionally i have to say, that i don't understand what you were calculating. If you put in SI-units in your equation, you will see that something is missing I'm talking about the gravitational constant G... but thats not the only point.